# How to combine rows after Pandas Groupby function

Tags: pandas, groupby

May I know how to combine several rows into one single row after I used Pandas groupby function?

In below example, I would like to to group the data by Employee ID, Customer Last Name and Customer First Name. Then I want all his dependents' data listed in the same row.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide data to reproduce your example?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for here is pandas.pivot(). It will transform your table from long to wide format. I first adapted your "Dep Relationship" column so that each child has a unique identifier within each Employee-ID.

Then called the function with the "Employee ID" as the index, the Relationship as the "column-generating variable" and the "Dep Name" and "Dep birth date" as the values filling the wide table.

```
Employee_ID = [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678]
First_name = ["Mohammed", "Mohammed", "Mohammed", "Mohammed", "Tony", "Tony"]
Last_name = ["Formal","Formal", "Formal", "Formal", "Smith", "Smith"]
Dep_first_name= ["Adm", "Fareeda", "Oasis", "Rain", "Anna", "Theo"]
Dep_relationship= ["Child1", "Child2", "Child3","Child4", "Child1", "Child2"]
Dep_birth_date = ["20/01/2006", "08/01/2001", "30/01/2013", "04/01/1999", "04/08/2008", "26/12/2004"]

zipped = list(zip(Employee_ID ,First_name , Last_name, Dep_first_name, Dep_relationship, Dep_birth_date ))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns=["Employee_ID ","First_name", "Last_name", "Dep_first_name", "Dep_relationship", "Dep_birth_date "])
```

```
pd.pivot(df, index="Employee_ID ", columns="Dep_relationship", values=["Dep_first_name","Dep_birth_date "])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `drop_duplicates` :

Define the columns you take into account:

```
unique_columns = Seq("Employee Id", "Customer Last name", "Customer First Name")
```

But it seems to me that the column Employee Id is enough, as you have only one person per Employee Id so you can define :

```
unique_columns = Seq("Employee Id", "Customer Last name", "Customer First Name")
```

Then you can write:

```
import pandas as pd 

unique_columns = Seq("Employee Id", "Customer Last name", "Customer First Name")
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=unique_columns)
```